# Tensorflow: how to run summary operation without triggering dequeue

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to write a script with Tensorflow to train a network. I have some requirements:

1. I need to use the `FIFOqueue` to load training dataset as well as the validation dataset; The `num_epoches` for the training dataset is set to `10`, but `num_epoches` for the validation dataset is set to `1` only, because in testing, we only need to run the whole validation dataset once.
2. I need to test the network after several training steps with the validation dataset, not in a separate script using the checkpoint file saved by the training script;
3. I need to store the `loss`, `accuracy_validation` data into a summary file, to visualize in Tensorboard.

However,

1. I found that every time I run the code `sess.run(summary_op)`, it actually would trigger a dequeue operation of the input data, which was not what I expected.
2. And, after several steps, I need to test the network with the **whole** validation dataset, while `sess.run(test_acc)` will only use a batch of the validation dataset to test the network.

So how to solve these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

The [MonitoredSession](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py) and [SessionRunHooks](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/session_run_hook.py) let you run summaries at the same time as you run normal training, so examples aren't dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data points from sess run and add them directly to the summary without running summary_op, e.g.:

```
step, _, loss_value, cur_learning_rate = sess.run([global_step, train_op, avg_loss, lr])
...
summary = tf.Summary()
summary.value.add(tag='train/loss_values', simple_value=loss_value)
summary.value.add(tag='train/learning_rates', simple_value=cur_learning_rate)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```

This way the queue will not be consumed by your summary_op.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to run the summary op at the same time as the training operation.

```
_, loss_value, summary = sess.run([train_op, avg_loss, summary_op])
```

That way you dequeue only once.