# Tensorflow manual evaluation with tf.estimators

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow api `tf.estimator` to train and evaluate models, building a custom estimator as explained [in this blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/creating-custom-estimators-in-tensorflow.html), and running the process with this convenient way:

```
run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=save_interval_secs,
                                    keep_checkpoint_max=keep_checkpoint_max,
                                    save_summary_steps=save_summary_steps,
                                    model_dir=logdir)
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn,
                                   config=run_config)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=train_steps)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=eval_steps, throttle_secs=eval_interval_secs)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

This process is very efficient to train and monitor `tf.metrics` metrics into Tensorboard (e.g. with `tf.metrics.accuracy`).

For one of my projects, I would like to add some more (complicated) metrics coming from a standalone python function, and visualize them in the Tensorboard. This function would take as an argument the training logdir (to load the model and run it on data) and would return some scalar (or tensor) to be monitored into the Tensorboard.

Last but not least, the function will need the GPU resources, so I expect this function to be called after evaluation:

```
Train xx steps => Evaluation xx steps => Custom metrics => Train xx steps => ...
```

I was thinking about using `tf.summary.FileWriter` and/or Training Hooks (see [Tensorflow documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20180925064834/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Training_Hooks)) but I don't know how to use them in a straightforward way with `tf.estimator` api.

Thank you very much for your help!

M.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can manually add data points to the TensorBoard logs from Python code (as opposed to using `tf.summary.*` ops) using [`tf.Summary`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Summary) and [`add_summary`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter#add_summary), see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576099/1782792). I guess you would still need hooks to do it at the right times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was thinking to do that, but I really don't know how to use hooks to do it at the right time...

Comment: I was trying to use some tf.metric operations (accuracy, AUC) during training which required resetting the metric every few steps since they are by default "streaming" operations which accumulate over the whole session.

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4814#issuecomment-353021133) which extended tf.train.SessionRunHook. It might be a good example to learn from for writing your own hook.